# Using RecyclerView inside ViewPager inside ContraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-constraintlayout

I'm using a `ConstraintLayout` for my view. Inside it I placed a `ViewPager` and one of the views that the adapter contains is a `RecyclerView`.

When I try to put just images, there's a missing height where I can't scroll anymore. That height looks to be the same than the space I'm using on the top (`Toolbar` + `TabLayout`).

**When using `RelativeLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` it works**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/toolbarColor">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                style="@style/RippleEffect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:padding="7dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                style="@style/RippleEffect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeToolbar"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/homeViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeTabLayout"

        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what I see (see the last Darth Vader)

[image]

Comment: I had a similar case and it was indeed because of the Toolbar. I made the toolbar scrollable and it got fixed like that. You can either make your toolbar scrollable or use a paddingBottom in the viewpager

Comment: Using `paddingBottom` wouldn't be the solution, as I don't want to calculate the missing bottom for the view. That would be a quick workaround but not the solution, don't you agree?

Comment: Just got the answer @Lukingan. I just posted the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by adding

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

To the ViewPager

Comment: That's great you solved it. But why you put TabLayout outside ViewPager tag? [Reference on developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) clearly describes that TabLayout should be placed inside ViewPager

Comment: "If you're using a ViewPager together with this layout, you can call setupWithViewPager(ViewPager) to link the two together. This layout will be automatically populated from the PagerAdapter's page titles" then "This view also supports being used as part of a ViewPager's decor, and can be added directly to the ViewPager in a layout resource file like so" that means you can do either way, but thank you for clarifying this.